# Ordering an ArrayList<BigDecimal> with bubble sort

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bubble-sort

I'm trying to order an  Arraylist which contains BigDecimal value of money from the largest to the smallest.
That's my code:

```
 public void bubble_sort(ArrayList<String> nameArray, ArrayList<BigDecimal> priceArray){
    for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < priceArray.size() - 1; j++){
            if (priceArray.indexOf(j) > priceArray.indexOf(j+1)){
                int temp = priceArray.indexOf(j);
                priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j+1));
                priceArray.set(j+1, BigDecimal.valueOf(temp));
            }
        }
    }
    Log.v("Ordering array", priceArray.toString());

}
```

But the order is still the same of the original array.
What should I do?

Comment: Use `priceArray.get(j).compareTo(priceArray.get(j+1)) > 0` instead of this: `priceArray.indexOf(j) > priceArray.indexOf(j+1)`

Comment: Thank you, but now it print "-1" for each price, not the value. --> If the size is 3, it prints [-1, -1, -1]. Maybe something else in my code is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the indices instead of the values.

Change this

```
if (priceArray.indexOf(j) > priceArray.indexOf(j+1)){
    int temp = priceArray.indexOf(j);
    priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j+1));
    priceArray.set(j+1, BigDecimal.valueOf(temp));
}
```

to

```
if (priceArray.get(j).compareTo(priceArray.get(j+1) > 0){
    BigDecimal temp = priceArray.get(j);
    priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j+1));
    priceArray.set(j+1, temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it print "-1" for each price, not the value. --> If the size is 3, it prints [-1, -1, -1]. Maybe something else in my code is wrong?

Comment: @Nicola you were also setting the new value to the index instead of swapping them, should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes, thank you, now it works! I also change > 0 to < 0, becase I want the biggest value first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for what do you use the String Array nameArray? Didn't noticed it in your code. If I understood it well I think you want something like this:

```
    public void bubble_sort(ArrayList<String> nameArray, ArrayList<BigDecimal> priceArray){

        boolean swap=true;
        double temp=0;
        while (swap){
        swap=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.size()-1; i++){
       if (priceArray.indexOf(j) > priceArray.indexOf(j+1)){
            temp = priceArray.indexOf(j);
            priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j+1));
            priceArray.set(j+1, BigDecimal.valueOf(temp));
        }
        swap=true
        }
        }
}
                Log.v("Ordering array", priceArray.toString());
            }
}
```